# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize does not render in my ASP.Net page

Tags: asp.net, ajax

The code below does not render in my ASP.NET page, and on click of the button my page posts back.

Sys dot WebForms dot PageRequestManager dot _initialize('ScriptManager1', document dot getElementById('form1'));
Sys dot  WebForms dot PageRequestManager dot getInstance() dot _updateControls(['tUpdatePanel1'], [], [], 90);

although i see the code below at the bottom of the page

Sys dot Application dot initialize();

I have a scriptmanager and an updatepanel in the page.
The updatepanel contains a label and a button in the contenttemplate section.
On click of the button the label is supposed to display some text.

I am using Visual Studio 2005 and I have installed the ASP.NET AJAX extensions.
I have referenced System.Web.Extensions
and System.Web in my project and I am using a WebApplication.

I have also copied the entries below in my config file

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

removed the tag 
xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy" from my web.config...

[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx)
[weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/10/gotcha-don-t-use-xhtmlconformance-mode-legacy-with-asp-net-ajax.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/10/gotcha-don-t-use-xhtmlconformance-mode-legacy-with-asp-net-ajax.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. Its solved by using The real problem is I have used tdXXXXX = de('_ctl0_CPB_XXXXX');

where de is a function function de(clID)

```
    {
        return document.getElementById(clID);  
    }
```

Previously the control was rendered correctly as _ctl0_CPB_XXXXX, now it has appeneded an extra 0 ie. _ctl00_CPB_XXXXX. This is used throught the application, and its causing the javaScripts failures. Any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

EnableEventValidation="false" in the page directive should solve the problem